# Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Comm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database-migration

I'm following a video on GraphQL ([min 1.28.22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuN94qNwQmM)), and when I run the command "dotnet ef migrations add AddPlatformToDb", it returns the following issue:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CommanderGQL.Data.AppDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'CommanderGQL.Data.AppDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Despite writing the same things, it doesn't create any issues in the video.

`CommanderGQL.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager" Version="7.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="13.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.Entityframework" Version="13.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "pa55w0rd!"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

`appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CommandConStr" : "Server=localhost,1433;Database=CommandsDB;User Id=sa;Password=pa55w0rd!"
  }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
using CommanderGQL.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CommanderGQL
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        //public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
            (Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommandConStr")));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // Configure production environment here
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // Configure endpoints here
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`Platform.cs`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CommanderGQL.Models
{
    public class Platform
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`AppDbContext.cs`:

```
using CommanderGQL.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CommanderGQL.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you please share your Program.cs file?

Comment: I just updated the request by adding the file.
I left it as default when creating the project.

Comment: @GuruStron (I forgot to tag you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an application using "new" (since .NET 6) minimal hosting model (which is used since .NET 6 templates). You basically have 2 options:

1. Remove the `Startup.cs` and move it contents to `Program.cs` file, everything from `ConfigureServices` should be called on `builder.Services` (instead of `services`), and everything from `Configure` should be called on `app` (possibly some modifications should me made):

   ```cs
   builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
            (builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommandConStr")));
   // ...
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   ```
2. Rewrite your app and switch back to the [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which can use the `Startup`

Without this changes your code in `Startup` is not applied, so the context is not set up correctly for migrations.

See also:

- [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-8.0)